# DispatchQueue.main.async doesn't have access to escaping closures params?

Tags: swift, closures

Help me understand something please, i have this function:

```
 func getUserDetailsRequestFor(userId: String, completion: @escaping([DataObject?]?, ApiError?, NSError?) -> () ) {
    let token = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token") ?? ""
    let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Authorization": "Bearer " + token]

    let endPoint = networkManager.buildURLforEndpoint(endpoint: ApiEndPoints.getUserByID.rawValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "{id}", with: userId))
    let request = networkManager.buildURLRequest(withEndpoint: endPoint, andHttpMethod: "Get", andHeaders: headers, andJsonBody: nil)

    networkManager.dataTaskWith(with: request) { (apiData, error) in
        completion(apiData?.data, apiData?.error, error)
    }
}
```

That i call like this:

```
func getUserDetails() {
    NetworkRouter.shared.getUserDetailsRequestFor(userId: "3") { (apiData, apiError, error) in
       print("this line get executed first, and i have access to apiData, apiError, error")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           print("this line get executed second, and i  don't have access to apiData, apiError, error")
        }
    }
}
```

I've put the print statements to illustrate my exact problem. I don't understand why i don't have access to the escaping closures params in the second print statement.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an error somewhere? Because when I reproduce this code I do have access to all parameters.

Comment: @Thomas What kind of error would i be looking for? The code builds fine, and there are no "yellow" errors anywhere. I have some others calls that are built just like this, and this one has this minor issue. What's different is that i call this method in "viewDidAppear". The other networks calls that work perfectly fine, i make inside IBActions.

Comment: If you have no errors then it must not be it. Under your first print, when you start typing apiData, does it auto complete with the proper type or does it show `<<error type>>`. Otherwise I would suggest restarting Xcode, cleaning the project, deleting the derived data folder etc.. and see if it still happens

Comment: Okay so deleting the project, getting it back from git, and typing in the same function  again actually worked. So freaking weird.. anyway thanks and this can be marked as resolved.

Comment: Yeah sometimes it does that. Usually a clean/removal of derived data/restart of Xcode fixes all weird bugs you're having. Glad it worked!